# jQuery table data sorter plugin for multiple <th> rows in one table

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm having one table with two table headings <th>. I need to sort two different sets by using jquery table sorting.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="listtable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Heading Set1 - A</th>
   <th>Heading Set1 - B</th>
   <th>Heading Set1 - C</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Heading Set2 - A</th>
   <th>Heading Set2 - B</th>
   <th>Heading Set2 - C</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

The scripts for sorting a single TH is as follows:

```
$(function() 
{ 

  $(".listtable").tablesorter({ 

  sortList : [[1,0]], 

  widgets: ["zebra", "columns"], 

  widgetOptions: { 
    columns: [ "primary", "secondary", "tertiary" ], 
    columns_thead : true, 
    columns_tfoot : true 
 } 

 });
```

I am able to sort a single set of TH, but I need to add another set TH and TBODY in the existing table. My scripts doesn't allow to sort two sets in a single table.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this pplugin,

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

DataTables allows you to sort by multiple columns at the same time. DataTables also provides a method to add your own sorting functions, to extend those built into DataTables. This can be very useful if you wish to sort on data formats such as currency and non-Javascript standard date formats (this natural sort algorithm is a popular useage).

Comment: thanks for your information. but, i couldn't able to use datatables. i should use table sorter plugin only in my project. do you have any idea about this same scenario in table sorter plugin.

Comment: your example explain sort about multi column sorting. but, I need one sort scripts which has sorting two set of TH in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this reference](http://www.idocs.com/tags/tables/_THEAD.html), but I couldn't find the exact wording in the [W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html). It says that tables are only allowed one `thead` and one `tfoot` per table. Multiple `tbody`'s are fine.

So, instead of having two `thead`, just replace it with a `tbody` and add the class `tablesorter-infoOnly` so that the plugin ignores the contents. Like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="listtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading Set1 - A</th>
            <th>Heading Set1 - B</th>
            <th>Heading Set1 - C</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="tablesorter-infoOnly">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading Set2 - A</th>
            <th>Heading Set2 - B</th>
            <th>Heading Set2 - C</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but, It's controlling only one sections only. i need two sets of table sorting as primary & secondary sections in one table. the table sorting is not initialized in secondary <thead>.